# jQuery.post() not working in chrome but works in FF

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I am using `jQuery.post()` to post data to a processing page which returns a result and the jQuery code react on this result, either adding a success message or failure message depending on the result. However it isnt working in chrome. In firefox it adds the info to the database(which is what the process page does) and then runs the success message. but in chrome it does nothing. when i try to refresh in chrome it says the form has been submitted and gives the resending data warning. But the jquery code is supposed to prevent the form being submitted via normal means.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function()
{   
$j('body').delegate('#submit_form_qr','submit',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
      $j("#process_info").removeClass().addClass('loading').html("Loading...").fadeIn("slow");

    $j.post('<?php echo $config['asf_root']; ?>/modules/quick_reply_process.php',{
    quick_reply:$j('#quick_reply_ta').val(),
    user_name :'<?php echo $template->user_name; ?>',
    quoting: '<?php echo $template->original_poster; ?>',
    subject: '<?php echo $template->post_subject; ?>',
    forum_id: '<?php echo $template->forum_id; ?>',
    topic_id: '<?php echo $template->topic_id; ?>'
    }, function(data)
    {

        if(data != 0)
        {   
            jQuery("#process_info").removeClass().addClass('subject_okay').html("Replied Successfully!").fadeIn("slow");

        }
        else
        {
            jQuery("#process_info").removeClass().addClass('subject_error').html(data).fadeIn("slow");
        }
    })

    return false;
});
```

Does anyone know why chrome isnt using the jQuery properly?

Comment: Does chrome show an error if you press `Ctrl+Shift+J` ?

Comment: never knew of that feature(im new to chrome). It brings up the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( at this line:
$j.('#submit_btn').colorbox({width:'450px', height:'250px'});
asf_is_absolutely_awesome-ex:768Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    });

Edit: Ive fixed it now: that error line has a period after $j and it shouldnt have. Thanks for the help. Dont know why FF and firebug never showed any errors.

Answer (score -1):

Add a semicolon before `return false`